# Call Fastlane actions from a ruby module

Tags: ruby, fastlane

I'm trying to make a ruby module with some helper functions that I use in the Fastfile. It looks as follows:

```
lane :a do |options|
  Utils.foo
end

module Utils
  def self.foo
    get_info_plist_value(...)
  end
end
```

When I try to run the lane I get this error: `undefined method 'get_info_plist_value' for Utils:Module`.

I've tried the following ways to solve this problem:

- adding `extend Utils` after the module definition
- including `Fastlane` or `Fastlane::Actions` into the module

These didn't help me.

Are there any other ways to solve the problem?

Comment: is it a gem? There is a little mess between namings, somewhere you wrote `fastlane` and somewhere `fastfile`. Can you please verify?

Comment: @zhisme, Yes, Fastlane is a gem. Fastfile is a file where you write code using Fastlane (as in my example). This is the Fastlane documentation - https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've gotten a util like this to work using dependency injection:

```
lane :a do |options|
  Utils.call(self)
end

module Utils
  def initialize(lane)
     @lane = lane
  end

  def self.call(lane)
     new.execute(lane)
  end

  def execute
     @lane.get_info_plist_value(...)
  end
end
```

If you look at the anatomy of a declared "lane" (`:a`, for example), each action (like [get_info_plist_value](http://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/get_info_plist_value/)) is executed within [Fastlane::Lane's](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/fastlane/lib/fastlane/lane.rb#L17) block, which was instantiated by the [Fastfile](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/fastlane/lib/fastlane/fast_file.rb#L86).

Although possible, writing utils that call Fastlane actions should be used sparingly. This seems fairly out of scope from intended usages of Fastlane. I think the "right" way to approach something like this is to actually [write a custom action](http://docs.fastlane.tools/create-action/) (a bit more verbose, but likely the more maintainable option).

As the saying goes, "Don't fight the framework!"